# node.js Command Line Interface app on windows

Tags: node.js, npm, command-line

I am creating a simple CLI (Command line interface) application using *NodeJs*, involving two files:

**package.json:**

[image]

**index.js**

[image]

I want to print "hello world" to *STDOUT* and it is working when running command `$ node index.js`

But I want to use it globally via command *test*. So, I put a **bin** entry in *package.json*. Then build the application using `npm link .`. But then when I run "test" command, *Windows* shows me the following error:

[image: error screenshot]

How can I use `console.log` in separate app?

Thank you!

Comment: I think npm reads the shebang to create a correct `.bat` (`.cmd`?) on Windows – try adding `#!/usr/bin/env node` as the first line of `index.js`.

Answer (score 0):

In `package.json` file, you need to write the code as follows:

```
"name" : "test",
"version": "1.0.0",
"scripts": {
   "start": "node index.js",
   "build": "webpack",
},
...
...
```

after this, use the command `npm start` to run the application.

Comment: Yeah, but it is not what i want. :( I want run script only with cmd "test"

Comment: it is not possible, you need to write the npm

Answer (score 0):

1- Create **bin** folder in root folder and place your index.js inside the bin.
type the shebang code on the first line of index.js:

bin/index.js

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

console.log("hello world");
```

2- Add below code into the package.json file.

```
"bin": {
   "test": "./bin/index.js" //this is relative path
}
```

3-finally run this code on command line

```
npm link
```

now you run "test" in your command line, it will log "hello world"

note:pay attention to the relative path that i mentioned above.